# Multiple String replacement using codeigniter

Tags: php, string

I know there must be a better way of writing this i just can not find it or am not asking the right question.

How would i wright multiple str_replace in one statement?

Here is my code

```
function create() {
if(array_key_exists('createFolder',$_POST)){
  $data = array(
    'folderName' => $this->input->post('folderName')
 // 'time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s',now())
  );
  $data = str_replace(' ', '_', $data);
  $data = str_replace('.', '_', $data);
  $data = str_replace('?', '_', $data);
  $datestring = "Year: %Y Month: %m Day: %d - %h:%i %a";
  $time = time();
  // $data = str_replace(' ', '_', $data);
  $this->index_model->createFolder($data, $datestring, $time);
}
$this->foldercreated();
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use an array:

```
$data = str_replace(array(' ', '.', '?'), '_', $data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an array like `$data = str_replace(array(' ', '.', '?'), '_', $data);`